# Why isn't window-snap working on Ubuntu 12.04 + gnome shell

Tags: 12.04, gnome, virtualbox, snap-windows

I am trying to get the window-snap feature to work but cannot.

I started with Ubuntu 12.04 (installed on a VirtualBox with Windows 7 hosting). I can't get 3D acceleration to work on VirtualBox, so Unity 2d is running and doesn't have snap (since compiz isn't running, I assumed).

Following some googling, I found that you can set Unity 2d to use compiz. Tried that and my system didn't seem to like that either.

Next step, I tried switching to gnome shell, where I read that window snap is integrated. I installed gnome shell using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Gnome shell works fine, but I still don't have window snap! Is there any way to get this simple feature to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved it. Apparently gnome shell has the same problem that it needs 3d acceleration turned on, otherwise it defaults to a skinned-down called gnome panel, which does not have windows snap.

I will keep the question and answer in case someone find them useful.